# Macro generic formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with four columns (A-D) as below:

```
1   XYZ     100     800
2   XYZ     250     820
3   XYZ     500    1100
4   XYZ   4,000    1200
```

I want to compute the column E values as below :

E1 = (D1-D1)*C1
E2 = (D2-D1)*C1 
E3 = (D3-D1)*C1+(D3-D2)*C2 
E4 = (D4-D1)*C1+(D4-D2)*C2+(D4-D3)*C3 
and so on if there are additional rows

Expected Results: E1=0, E2=2000, E3=100000, E4=185000

Is it possible to generalize this formula? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to generalize this formula in the cell, because the formula needs to *grow*.  Also, there is a character limit for formula in Excel cells (see @pnuts comment, below), so you can't reliably use VBA to "build" the formula because after a certain number of rows, you'll exceed that threshold. And while your use-case may not run in to this limitation, in cases like this I would prefer the simplicity of a UDF over a VBA subroutine that "builds" a long formula string.

You *can* write a custom function that computes the value by iterating the range.  This works on your example data. Place the code in a standard code module.

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal clStart As Range, ByVal clEnd As Range) As Variant
'Pass only the cell address for the first cell ("D1") and the last cell ("D4")
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myVal As Double

    Application.Volatile

    If Not clStart.Column = clEnd.Column Then
        'These cells should be in the same column, if not
        ' display an error
        myVal = CVErr(2023)
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If

    Set rng = Range(clStart.Address, clEnd.Address)

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count - 1
        Set r = rng.Cells(i)
        myVal = myVal + _
            ((clEnd.Value - r.Value) * r.Offset(0, -1).Value)
    Next

EarlyExit:
    GetValue = myVal
End Function
```

Comment: Is the 255 limit to the # of references that can be contained in a formula? I swear I ran in to an issue like that before.

Answer (score 0):

quite late, but why couldn't you just use
..
E4 = D4*SUM(C$1:C3)-SUMPRODUCT(C$1:C3,D$1:D3) 
..
instead of 
E4 = (D4-D1)*C1+(D4-D2)*C2+(D4-D3)*C3

To prevent a performance hit, if it's possible to use temp columns, you could create columns to store partial sums of C and C*D.